# Pyqgis: How to use GDAL-Tool 'Rasterinfo'

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I have a couple of raster layers and for my next Plugin, I want to get the corner coordinates for each layer.

My idea was to use the GDAL-Tool 'Rasterinformation' which gives as an output a lot of information about a raster file including the corner coordinates. However, after running the tool, the output is presented in the GUI.

[image]

How do I manage this in PyQGIS? My code so far is the following:

```
    def selectRasters(self):
    inputDir = self.getInputPath()
    for lyr in glob.glob(os.path.join(inputDir, "*xyz")):
        info = []
        processing.run('gdal:rasterinfo', lyr, False, True, True, info)
```

My hope is that I have all the information as a list and then I can do something like `raster upper left = info[5]` and so on.

Long story short I want add the corner coordinates into a variable. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is just to access the corner co-ordinates, then perhaps something like the following would work better for you. This is just an example of using the `extent()` method of [QgsRasterDataProvider](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterDataProvider.html) to return a raster layer extent as a [QgsRectangle](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRectangle.html) object then store each of its corners as co-ordinate tuples in a dictionary. Of course you don't have to use a dictionary- you could store them as a nested list, list of tuples- whatever. I just think a dictionary with each corner as a key makes retrieving them easier and reduces the potential for confusion or mistakes.
You can then work with each corner x and y values by indexing the tuple items, so you can easily use them to create a `QgsPointXY` object, return it as well known text- or whatever you like.

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer() #Raster layer object
rect = lyr.dataProvider().extent()
corners = dict()
corners['top_left'] = (rect.xMinimum(), rect.yMaximum())
corners['top_right'] = (rect.xMaximum(), rect.yMaximum())
corners['bottom_right'] = (rect.xMaximum(), rect.yMinimum())
corners['bottom_left'] = (rect.xMinimum(), rect.yMinimum())
print(corners)
upper_left_x = corners['top_left'][0]
upper_left_y = corners['top_left'][1]
pnt = QgsPointXY(upper_left_x, upper_left_y)
print(pnt.asWkt())
```

If you really want to work with `gdalinfo`, you *could* use this approach to create a text file as a temporary output, read each line into a list, and retrieve the x and y values from e.g. the top left corner, but it seems unnecessary for your task:

```
import processing
lyr = iface.activeLayer() #Raster layer object
outfile = 'C:\\Users\\Ben\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Result.txt'
processing.run('gdal:gdalinfo', {'INPUT': lyr, 'OUTPUT': outfile})
with open(outfile, "r") as info:
    info_text = []
    for line in info:
        info_text.append(line)

print(info_text[34])
top_left_x = info_text[34][13:25]
top_left_y = info_text[34][26:38]
print(top_left_x, top_left_y)
```

Run the algorithm first and check the log output to make sure you are getting the right line/ list item.

There are different approaches to reading the text file into a list. You could start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list) and make up your own mind, but that part of the process is off topic for gis.stackexchange.